# Error associated with Sersic Profile calculations?

Tags: galaxy, data-analysis, sloan-dss

I am working on a Bayesian analysis project for class using data I gathered some data from NASA's Sloan Atlas (http://www.nsatlas.org/). One of the variables I am dealing with is the Sérsic Index (calculated by http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-6256/142/1/31/pdf).
I am wondering if there is some error associated with this value.  I hope to model each galaxies Sersic index as a gaussian, but I can´t wrap my head around what to write as the error.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I see nothing in the paper you linked talking about how to calculate the Sersic Index. Would you mind specifying a specific page, section, equation, etc.?